# Nsight or other Direct3D debbuger/performance analyser for Visual Studio 2012 (GeForce)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx, visual-studio-2012, nsight

I am searching for any kind of Direct3D 10/11 debbuger/performance analyser for Visual Studio 2012.

I have found very nice application named NVidia PerfHUD, but I noticed that it's depreciated.

New one is NVidia Nsight. Unfortunately, it's designed for Visual Studio 2008/2010.

Is there any option to **connect NVidia Nsight to Visual Studio 2012**?

If no, **are there any other programs of that type** (easy to use monitors that will allow me to check the performance of my Direct3D C++ application)?

Comment: Might help to say why you can't do your OpenGL profiling/debugging in VS2010+Nsight.  You don't own it?  You're using C++11 features that require the newer compiler?

Comment: I'm using Direct3D not OpenGL. I have VS2012 and like its new features (but I can live without them ;p). If I have to migrate to VS2010 (because there are no other options) I will consider it.

Comment: Well, you can still use VS2012 as your editor, and just fire up VS2010 when you profile, at least until nVidia releases an updated version of Nsight.  And sorry about DX vs OpenGL, silly mistake on my part, though the same tools should work for both.

Comment: Thanks :-) I guess I will do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try it myself, (Using VS2010 and didn't move to 2012 yet),
but it shows that there is an integrated support in Visual Studio 2012 for DX Debugging.

Take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/11/08/10235150.aspx):

Comment: I think DX Debugging only works for D3D projects (not openGL).